# How to use datediff mysql function in a mysql query on data frames in R using sqldf package

Tags: mysql, r, datediff

I have 2 data frames. I have to use a mysql query on these 2 frames based on a condition which subtracts the date columns in the 2 frames. So, I am using sqldf package to use data frames in a mysql query, but it is not letting me use DATEDIFF function to subtract dates. Can anyone please let me know how can I solve this problem and use datediff since sqldf is not accepting this function.

Comment: This question is likely to recive poor atention because of your low aceptance rate. Please go to some of your question an accept the answers there if you find them satisfying to your question. Futhermore, a reproductable example would be usefull, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Luciano: Thanks. I missed that.. Done that now.. Hope someone helps me now.. I am really stuck coz of this issue. :)

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example?

Comment: a<-sqldf("select b.id  as viewed, c.id as bought,
count(c.id) as quantity from b JOIN
c on
b.email=c.email where datediff(date(c.created),date(b.viewed))<=14 group by 1,2");
This is the code..

Comment: Questions should be reproducible.  Cut down your data to a manageable size that still illustrates your problem and post it and your code in the question using `dput`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example